# Fj cruiser rear diff lock

Tags: toyota, differential, fjcruiser

I bought a 2009 FJ cruiser and I can see the rear differential lock motor on the rear differential but I don't have any switch inside to activate it ?

Is there any way to add a switch to be able to use it ?

Comment: I would be careful with this. If the motor exists without a manual control for it, then the control would be automatic through the PCM (Powertrain Control Unit). If you manually trigger it, the PCM may not know what do with that. Does the manual for the car say anything about this control? Also, is there information on the OBDII port about the state of this lock motor?

Comment: I'm almost positive there is a button. It's either left of the steering wheel or in the center under the HVAC and radio. It should say RR Diff Lock or have a picture of the 4WD system with the front wheels pointed right.

Comment: What is your trim package?

Comment: If you can post your trim package we can tell you if the car comes with the feature.  If you have a TRD it definitely does and there would be a manual button to engage it.